# Resteasy in-built exceptions not caught in the exception mapper

Tags: spring, exception, resteasy

I have written some exception mappers to catch and handle the in-built rest easy exceptions like NotFoundException,MethodNotAllowedException, etc., Sample code as shown:

```
@Provider
public class NotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<org.jboss.resteasy.spi.NotFoundException>
{
    @Override
    Response toResponse(org.jboss.resteasy.spi.NotFoundException exception) {
         return Response.status(500).build();
         }
}
```

I have also written a try catch block in my web filter class. Whenever a NotFoundException occurs, it is not caught in the mapper, but it goes to the catch block in the Filter.

Whereas I have tried another exception mapper class to handle JsonParsingException. This is working correctly and giving a proper response from the mapper whenever a Json Parse exception occurs.

The issue is only with the case of resteasy exceptions.
Also, the Provider has been registered in the application context using the include-filter tag inside component scan.

Please guide me as to what needs to be done to catch rest easy in-built exceptions in the mapper class itself.

Regards,
RM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Annotating the NotFoundExceptionMapper with @Component should fix it (or adding NotFoundExceptionMapper as a bean to your application context (xml-file)).

When your Spring context is started the NotFoundExceptionMapper should be registered (you should something like "Pre-instantiating singletons in ... " in your logging)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my demo project

1) a simple RESTful app with 3 java files:

1.1) RestNotFoundExceptionHandler.java

```
package demo.app;

import javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class RestNotFoundExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException e) {
        return Response.ok().entity(e.toString() + "\n").type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
    }
}
```

1.2) AppRest.java

```
package demo.app;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/")
public class AppRest {
    @GET
    @Path("millis")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String refresh(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            return Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "\n";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString() + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

1.3) AppMain.java

```
package demo.app;

import javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.tjws.TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer;

public class AppMain {
    private static final int PORT = 8080;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppRest appRest = new AppRest();
        TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer tjws = new TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer();
        tjws.setPort(PORT);
        tjws.setRootResourcePath("/rest");
        tjws.start();
        tjws.getDeployment().getRegistry().addSingletonResource(appRest);
        tjws.getDeployment().getProviderFactory().getExceptionMappers()
                .put(NotFoundException.class, new RestNotFoundExceptionHandler());
    }
}
```

2) project dependencies, 4 jar files

```
jaxrs-api-3.0.9.Final.jar
resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
tjws-3.0.9.Final.jar
```

3) curl test cases:

3.1) normal case:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/millis
1419167594504
```

3.2) RestNotFoundExceptionHandler case:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/bad
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/bad
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same thing and fell into trouble while trying to map UnsupportedMediaTypeException.

According to http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/ExceptionHandling.html and the first line under Exception Mappers section it seems you can only map application Exceptions.

Comment: I have exact same problem, i've set @Provider annotation to my custom ExceptionMapper and also registered the mapper in web.xml and still no-effect the mapper doesn't handle the exceptions. I've tried to use RuntimeExceptions and Exception to extends but there is no differens....